# How to append to the arguments array ("$@" ) in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash

My script takes a list of files as arguments.  I want to add new argument to `$@` array. For a normal array named `files`, appending to the array would be `files+=(name_here.png)`. How do to I append to `$@`?

Answer (score 16):

I would refer to @hek2mgl answer as the best *array-specific* answer, but if your goal is to explicitly **extend** `$@` then go with this:

```
set -- "$@" '/path/to/file1' '/path/to/file2'
```

Comment: Why is eval needed here? `set -- "$@" "new_arg1" "new_arg2" ...` should work, right?

Comment: Not only is it not needed, it is incorrect. Consider the output of `set "a b"; eval set -- "$@" c; echo "$1"`; you'll see that the new first positional parameter is `a`, not `a b`.

Comment: @codeforester / @chepner; thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 8):

I would copy `$@` to an array and append to that:

```
files=( "${@}" )
files+=( name_here.png )
```

Then use `${files}` in the script rather than `${@}`.